# Issue with Windows Server backup

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I have windows server 2008 r2 installed, Only service running on it is hyper-v.

I am trying to take backup using windows server backup feature and it fails with following error in eventlog

The backup operation that started at '?2009?-?08?-?22T18:42:14.123000000Z' has failed because the Volume Shadow Copy Service operation to create a shadow copy of the volumes being backed up failed with following error code '2155348129'. Please review the event details for a solution, and then rerun the backup operation once the issue is resolved.

Above error itself is point to other event logs for more detail but i can't find anything in event logs

Then i ran following command

vssadmin list writers

It had following out of ordinary in list

Writer name: 'Microsoft Hyper-V VSS Writer'
   Writer Id: {66841cd4-6ded-4f4b-8f17-fd23f8ddc3de}
   Writer Instance Id: {d15c5f78-121c-464f-b23b-f285e919b05c}
   State: [8] Failed
   Last error: Inconsistent shadow copy

How could i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Do any of the VMs you're trying to back up contain dynamic disks? (That's in disk management within the VM, dynamic disks as opposed to basic disks. Not dynamically expanding VHDs)

[To quote Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958662):

> When you perform a backup of the virtual machines, you must back up all volumes that host files for the virtual machine, including the InitialStore.xml file (in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V, by default) and the volume(s) containing the VHD(s) and configuration XML files. For example, if the virtual machine configuration files are stored on the D: volume, and the virtual machine virtual hard disk (VHD) files are stored on the E: volume, and InitialStore.xml file is stored on the C: volume, you must back up the C:, D: and E: volumes.
>   Virtual machines that do not have Integration Services installed will be put in a saved state while the VSS snapshot is created.
>   Virtual machines that are running operating systems that do not support VSS, such as Microsoft Windows 2000 or Windows XP, will be put in a saved state while the VSS snapshot is created.
>   Virtual machines that contain dynamic disks must be backed up offline.